# search and highlight text with Next and Previous button in ListView wpf

Tags: wpf, listview, search

Hi I want to develop a program in which user can search text in list of messages. Wherever text is matched in message, highlight that text. Also provide Next and Previous buttons to navigate through search results.
I got an example which highlights all search results right on entering text in searchbox, but I want Next and Previous functionality in that.

Comment: Did you try coding anything?

Comment: I have not coded anything. I found a demo code here which highlights all searched result and does not display Next/Previous buttons. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/409275/Highlight-Searched-Text-in-WPF-ListView

Comment: I want to do searching functionality like in Skype. It displays a search box. when user enters a text in it, it highlights that text matched in messages and also displays Next and Previous buttons.

Comment: @pratik03 Did you solve it?